# generic lambdas mem_fn with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, lambda

I am trying to convert lambdas to `mem_fn` in C++.

I have encountered an issue with gcc and generic lambdas.
Does anyone know if something can be done for gcc?

```cpp
#include <functional>

// Standard lambda
auto std_lambda = [](double x) -> double { 
    return 2. * x; 
};


// generic lambda
auto generic_lambda = [](auto x) { 
    auto two = static_cast<decltype(x)>(2.l);
    return two * x; 
};



void test()
{
    // convert lambdas to mem_fn
    // this call works on gcc/clang/msvc
    auto std_mem_fn = std::mem_fn( 
        & decltype(std_lambda)::operator() );

    // convert lambdas to mem_fn
    // this call works on clang/msvc
    // but fails on gcc
    auto generic_mem_fn = std::mem_fn( 
        & decltype(generic_lambda)::template operator()<double> );

    // By the way, I would be interested to make the 
    // mem_fn instantiation code more similar 
    // for generic and template lambdas
}
```

Test this code on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Gw40dA)  (works on clang, mscv, but not on gcc)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher : I am working on a proof of concept on how to extract lambda type. See https://github.com/pthom/type_name#log-lambdas-params--return-type--name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be a GCC bug, since it compiles if you "use" the generic lambda before building the `std::mem_fun`. By "using" I mean e.g. calling the lambda or storing the mem-fun pointer separately:

```
#include <functional>

auto generic_lambda = [](auto x) { 
    auto two = static_cast<decltype(x)>(2.l);
    return two * x; 
};

int main()
{
    // call the lambda ...
    generic_lambda(1.0);

    // or retrieve the mem-fun ptr
    auto unused = &decltype(generic_lambda)::template operator()<double>;    

    // now it compiles on GCC
    auto generic_mem_fn = std::mem_fn( 
        & decltype(generic_lambda)::template operator()<double> );
}
```

see [live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ibElrrifsYbeW1eF)

so you could use the following approach to make it GCC compatible:

```
auto ptr = &decltype(generic_lambda)::template operator()<double>;    
auto generic_mem_fn = std::mem_fn(ptr);
```

Comment: Thanks *a lot* for this thorough investigation !